# Sonarqube 5.2, LDAP plugin 1.5: users losing privileges at their next login?

Tags: ldap, sonarqube

I have installed SonarQube 5.2 and the LDAP plugin 1.5 a few hours ago. I am really happy about the easy configuration of the LDAP plugin in an Active Directory domain.

But I experience something which looks like a huge problem.

1) An AD user loads the web page of the SonarQube instance

- [behind the scenes] a user is being created (starting up from the headers of the HTTP request and the information present in the Active Directory)

2) An administrator of the platform (e.g. admin, default administrator of the platform) gives her some rights (e.g. add her to the sonar-administrators group)

- the web interface shows an updated set of rights for this user

3) The user starts a new session

- **!!!** The user has lost all of its rights. She doesn't belong anymore to the sonar-administrators group
- **(expected behavior)** the user gets an updated interface, with the menus reserved to the sonar-administrators group

Am I missing some important part of the documentation?

Comment: The user doesn't seem to lose her preferences (in terms of projects).

Comment: please find at [this address](https://gist.github.com/nilleb/31e13f11d5847a900986) a portion of the sonar.log. This could be an hint of the fact that I missed a part of the documentation, but which one? :-)

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. I'm still running the 1.4 plugin as going to 1.5 with the exact same configuration causes this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have configured SonarQube to use an external system to manage security, in this particular case Active Directory. So the default (and expected) behaviour is to delegate **both** the authentication and the authorizations to this system.

In your example, if you want the user to belong to some specific group, you have to configure this in your Active Directory. Next time the user logs in, he will be associated to this(those) group(s).

Note that the groups must exist in SonarQube otherwise this won't work (i.e. you have to manually add them in the "Security > Groups" ).

Comment: How can we disable this behavior? LDAP 1.4 didn't do this with the same exact configuration.

Comment: You mention a 'default' behavior. Does this mean that this default behavior can be changed ? (sometimes, AD modification policies can be *really* constraining)

Comment: Just a note about what you've mentioned in your last paragraph: the group name (in the SonarQube configuration) SHALL have the form groupname@domain (lowercase)

(I have seen this in the traces after having tried several other possibilities)

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Fabrice's answer, when you have a user or group in the AD that you want to have administration permissions to the SonarQube instance, go to:

<your sq instance>/roles/global

and add the user or the group to the **Administer System** global permission.

Comment: You don't need do mess around with groups, just go to Security > Global permissions and add your user there to give them admin